# Why is dot syntax working in this line of Objective-C code but without it does not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I cannot for the life of me figure this issue out. I have this line of code:

```
[  [cell textLabel]setText:justCourseNames [indexPath.row]   ];
```

And it works, however due to standards I have to follow I cannot use dot syntax. I figured I could just do this:

```
[  [cell textLabel]setText:justCourseNames [indexPath row]   ];
```

But Objective-C isn't having it. I know the [indexPath row] is valid because it works when I use it to get the rows using an NSLog but will not work for the above line of code.

Can anyone please explain why? I cannot make sense of it. My assumption is that it isn't passing what I think it is passing (even though the documentation says it's just a number).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a square bracket

```
[indexPath row]
```

will return the row of you indexPath, and

```
justCourseNames[...]
```

will select and item in your NSArray. The correct way to write this line of code is :

```
[  [cell textLabel]setText:justCourseNames [ [indexPath row] ]   ];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! (I feel stupid for not realizing that sooner..., my Objective-C is a bit rusty). I was banging my head off the wall trying to figure it out. 

I will mark your answer as solved as soon as Stack Overflow lets me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken on the formatting you're doing.

To access an object in an array (at least shorthand) you do:

`justCourseNames[i]`

---

With your `[  [cell textLabel]setText:justCourseNames [indexPath row]   ];`

You are missing the brackets to call the index you want from justCourseNames.

This is what you'll need to do:

`[  [cell textLabel]setText:justCourseNames[ [indexPath row] ]  ];`

---

The reason why your first example, `[  [cell textLabel]setText:justCourseNames [indexPath.row]   ];` works is because the dot notation does not mix with the brackets for calling an arrays index.

Answer (score 1):

[indexPath row] is a function that gets the row from the indexPath.

justCourseNames[*] gets an item from the justCourseNames array at index *.

If you want to get an item from the row index of the justCoursesNames array you need:

justCourseNames[[indexPath row]];

The inner set of brackets is for the function to get the row, and the outer brackets is for the array index.

While slightly off-topic, I would highly recommend reading a style-guide like https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide to get a better idea when/where dot notation vs brackets is better. Excerpt:

> Dot-notation should always be used for accessing and mutating
>   properties. Bracket notation is preferred in all other instances.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
> [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
> ```
>
> Not:
>
> ```
> [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
> UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate;
> ```

In this case, row is a property you are accessing, so you should probably be using indexPath.row.